# The difference between 'It is important that...' and 'It is important for...to...'

Tags: difference

Is there any difference between the following sentences (in its meaning)?

1. It is important for him to study in the UK.
2. It is important that he studies in the UK.

I also wonder if there is any difference in 'It is + adjective+ for + to infinitive' and 'It is + adjective + that...' in general.

Answer (score 1):

These two sentences mean essentially the same thing.  I see no difference in using one of them or the other.

Comment: I thought the first sentence expresses 'important for him', but the second sentence implies 'important (might be to someone) that he studies...'. Are these sentences also the same? 1. It is important for students to acquire computer literacy, 2. It is important that students acquire computer literacy.